# What's happening inside this Python decorator?

Tags: python, decorator

So my question pertains specifically to the decorator at the top of the example below.  I don't understand the 3rd line of the lowercasedecorator function.  I'm confused why it's returning a list, if it's in those square brackets, it means it's a list right?  Also, I don't completely understand the end of that line 'func(*args)', does that just mean arbitrary arguments of 'func' (which in this case would be displayPeople) ?

```
def lowercasedecorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        return [i.lower() for i in func(*args)]
    return wrapper

class People():
    totalpeople = 0
    def __init__(self, name, age, phone):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.phone=phone
        People.totalpeople += 1

    @lowercasedecorator
    def displayPeople(self):
        return self.name, self.age, self.phone

ben = People("bEn", "20", "5034950293")

print ben.displayPeople()
```

Comment: Hint: what type of object does `displayPeople` return without the decorator?

Comment: so displayPeople() returns... A list?  That kind of confuses me because ben = People("ben", "20", "4252454"), so I think of that as a tuple.

Comment: Hard to top the explanation in [PEP 318](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)

Answer (score 1):

```
def wrapper(*args):
    return [i.lower() for i in func(*args)]
```

The `*` syntax in the call to `func` (that is, `displayPeople`) passes the same positional arguments that `wrapper` received.

`wrapper` does indeed return a list.

Because of how decorators work, the function `wrapper` created with `func = displayPeople` *is* the decorated version of `displayPeople`.

So, the effect of the decorator is that the decorated version of `displayPeople` calls the undecorated version, lower-cases the returned values, and returns them as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Line #3 is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). The can be used instead of a for loop.

`func(*args)` is indeed unpacking the tuple that is being passed in on line 1.